# トランザクションへ任意の文字列を追加したい

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Solidity + Truffleを使用しています

送金した際に任意のメッセージを追加したいです

以下 solidity

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value, string comment);

function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - _value;
    balances[_to] = balances[_to] + _value;

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, msg.data);

    return true;
}
```

以下 truffle console

```
> con.transfer.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[1], 10, "abc")
> var str = web3.toAscii("トランザクションのinput")
> consol.log(str)
V¸Ç$ñR¾öÇ3O­
           W×r·2
`abc
```

abc が取得出来ました

今度は日本語を入力しました

```
> con.transfer.sendTransaction(web3.eth.accounts[1], 10, "いいね")
> var str = web3.toAscii("トランザクションのinput")
> consol.log(str)
M   e©§1K£ÇAAÝÇ¶r»R5ï\Æfñ1! Å
```

文字化け起こしました

全角が使用出来ないのかなと思い、（フロントのプログラムで）エンコードした値をセットすればと考えましたが、inputの切れ目(目的のデータ位置)がわからずメッセージだけ取り出す方法がわかりません

トークン送付、Eth送金時にメッセージを追加する方法例がある方教えていただけないでしょうか

---

bytesにすべきとアドバイスがあったのでsolidity変更しました

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value, bytes comment);

function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes comment) public returns (bool success) {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - _value;
    balances[_to] = balances[_to] + _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, msg.data);
    return true;
}
```

pythonでの実行(EVMではなくすみません)

成功する場合：ただし引数に含めているので不本意です

```
contract_instance.functions.transfer(W3.eth.accounts[1], 10, com2).transact({'from': ADDRESS_0})
```

NGな場合

```
contract_instance.functions.transfer(W3.eth.accounts[1], 10).transact({'from': ADDRESS_0, 'data': com2})

raise ValueError("Cannot set data in transact transaction")
```

`data`に含めれば良かったと思うのですが間違っていますでしょうか

Comment: というかすいません。bytes型とbytes1～32型があるんですね。私が想定していたのはbytes1～32型の方で、bytesの方は可変長なので結局stringとほとんど変わらず、msg.dataはbytes型のためこれを利用するのであれば私の回答で述べた効果は期待出来ないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value, string comment);

上記string commentの型をbytes32にして見たら如何ですか？
文字化けは解消しないかもしれませんが、可変長のstringとは違って固定長なのでinputの切れ目(目的のデータ位置)は固定されます。

たしか自分も試してエンコード無しの日本語は駄目だった記憶があります。

それと公式がbytes32型を推奨しているので、特別な理由が無い限りbytes32型を利用した方が良いです。
固定長でgasの節約が期待出来、eventのデータsizeも固定されたりと色々メリットがあります。

Comment: stringをbytes32に変更したところ、呼び出し側と形あっていないということでエラーになりました。呼び出し元でbytes32(comment)としたのですが`TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "string memory" to "bytes32".`とエラーになってしまいました

Comment: なんか誤解がある気がします。event宣言部分をevent Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value, bytes32 comment);にしてみて下さい。その後event発火する際に型変換等は必要ありません

Comment: フォローありがとうございます。        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, comment);
        ^------^
となり、発火の箇所でエラーになります。Transferの箇所に^------^が出ます。

Comment: すいません、msg.dataをそのまま渡していると思ったんですが、comment変数をローカルに一度入れているみたいですね。commentの型はbytes32になっていますか？msg.dataのデフォルトはbytes32なので、そのまま渡しているなら問題無いはずなのですが

Comment: コントラクトの引数を使うとうまく行くのですが、使わないようにするとうまく行かないです。元の質問後半に追記したので、よろしければ見ていただけると助かります。